# Symbols Enumeration callback function called more than once for the same symbol?

Tags: c, winapi, debug-symbols, dbghelp, dia

I've wrote a small program that uses the dbghelp library to print all the symbols for some executable.
The main enumeration function that i call is : SymEnumSymbols that should receive a callback that would be called for each symbol.
I tried to run the program on kernel32.dll and i have encountered 2 strange issues:

1) There are symbols that are situated in the same address but they are equal in all the fields values of the SYMBOL_INFO structure (besides the unique index filed) -
so how i can to distinguish between ? (for example: 0x6b814c23 -StringCopyWorkerW)

2) In some cases there are two symbols with the same characteristics in the same address . (When i opened the file in IDA i saw that there are two exported entries - but one is function and the other isn't (for example :WerGetFlag and WerGetFlagsWorker that are at 0x6b84c840).

Thanks!

here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL CALLBACK EnumSymProc(PSYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo,ULONG SymbolSize,PVOID   UserContext)
{
/* Print props of the current symbol */\
printf("%08x", pSymInfo->Address);
printf("|%d", pSymInfo->Tag);
printf("|%08x", pSymInfo->Flags);
printf("|%d", pSymInfo->TypeIndex);
printf("|%s\n", pSymInfo->Name);
return TRUE;
}
void main()
{
  DWORD64 BaseOfDll=0;
  DWORD currOpt = 0;
  HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
  SymInitialize(hProcess, NULL, FALSE);
  BaseOfDll =         SymLoadModule64(hProcess,NULL,"c:\\windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll",NULL,0,0);
  SymEnumSymbols(hProcess, BaseOfDll, NULL, EnumSymProc, NULL);
  SymUnloadModule64(hProcess, BaseOfDll);
  SymCleanup(hProcess);
 }
```

Comment: There is a question missing from your question.

Comment: I don't think there's anything stopping an executable from exporting two identical symbols.  There certainly isn't anything stopping two symbols from being at the same address, a function can have multiple names or two separate functions can be combined into one during optimization.

Comment: Thanks! i have searched this issue after you have commented and saw these optimization , Do you have a clue about the first part of my question ? why there are two same names ? (StringLengthWorkerW) - i don't see any distinction between the symbols.

Comment: `why there are two same names ? (StringLengthWorkerW)` - this can happen e.g. if that is an inline function being expanded more than once.

Comment: but on the same address ? this is strange.... I ran Dia2Dump and it outputs me these line: Function: [00014C23][0001:00004C23] StringCopyWorkerW
Function: [00014C23][0001:00004C23] StringCopyWorkerW - the same line two times

Comment: Possibly a compatibility fix, because some folks imported the symbol by ordinal, rather than name.